# searching string using grep

Tags: linux, grep

I am searching a string using grep but the output displays unwanted files along with the correct file.

Ex:-
xyz_utils.c Contains SAM22 keyword.

###### `grep` command:

```
ret=$(grep -irwE "${excluded_files[@]/#/--exclude=}" "\\b${LIST[$A]}\\b|${LIST[$A]}[-_.*>@^:.,~%&\(\)\{}]|\\b${LIST[$A]}\\b" \
                "$package/" |grep -v "$filters\|${excluded_dir[@]}" -c)
```

LIST[] -> Contains the list of words needs to be searched for.

###### Unwanted files displayed:

```
/home/sampath/SAM20_1.0.0/LICENSE.BSD:      from this software without specific prior written permission.
/home/sampath/SAM20_1.0.0/LICENSE.BSD:  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
/home/sampath/SAM20_1.0.0/LICENSE.BSD:  "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
/home/sampath/SAM20_1.0.0/LICENSE.BSD:  LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
/home/sampath/SAM20_1.0.0/LICENSE.BSD:  (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
/home/sampath/SAM20_1.0.0/LICENSE.BSD:  OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
.
.
/home/sampath/SAM20_1.0.0/README.txt:    Static libraries included in SAM software package:
/home/sampath/SAM20_1.0.0/README.txt:        Warning: This option should never be enabled in a production environment
.
.
```

###### Correct file displayed:

```
/home/sampath/SAM20_1.0.0/xyz_utils.c:SAM22
```

Comment: You tagged this question _shell_, which means "POSIX shell", but your code is definitely non-posix. Please tag the question with the shell you are actually using.

Comment: I recommend running your code with `-x` turned on, to see what `grep` commands are actually generated.

Comment: `I am searching a string` What string are you searching? `Correct file displayed:` So search for `SAM22`, why are you doing all that `"\\b${LIST[$A]}\\b|${LIST...`? Could you explain your code? Do you want to search the string `SAM22` in only `.c` files? Could you explain your goal?

Comment: \\b searches for word boundary. There are multiple keywords needs to be searched excluding few files and directories. So when grep searches for the string(SAM22), grep displays the file it contains the string and displays irrelevant files are also getting displayed as shown above.
My requirement is to display the file contains the string. No need of irrelevant files to be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I want to search for a string, like `SAM22`, within a group of files, this is what I do:

```
find /<directory> -name "*.<extension>" -exec grep "SAM22" {} /dev/null \;
```

For your information: `/dev/null` is a neat trick: as you might know, `grep "entry" <filename>` shows `entry` as a result (no filename), while `grep "entry" <filename1> <filename2>` shows `filename1:entry`, so by adding `/dev/null`, I can force the output to show the filename too.
In case you say "I don't need the whole line, containing `SAM22`, just the entry itself, this can be handled using the `-o` switch:

```
find /<directory> -name "*.<extension>" -exec grep -o "SAM22" {} /dev/null \;
```